# twitter count not getting updated

Tags: php, twitter

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="vertical" 
       data-counturl="<?=$link_base?>welcome/create41/<?=$identifier?>"
       data-url="<?=$link_base?>welcome/create41/<?=$identifier?>">
        Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
```

I have included a tweet button in my page but the count is not getting updated.

I also wanted to know if there is a delay in the count getting updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using a widget which pulls data directly from twitter, there is nothing you can do about it. Any sort of delay or mismatch will be because of twitter itself.